# How do I call a subset of subroutines with a Loop in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a series of subroutines (`Sub1`, `Sub2`, `Sub3`, etc). I want to call a subset of these subroutines based on user defined values. For example, subs 7 through 13.

I thought of using a loop based on the number in the name of subroutine, but it does not seem to work in VBA. Does anyone have suggestions?

Example Code:

```
Sub test()    
    Dim i As Integer    
    Dim Start As Integer    
    Dim End As Integer    
    Start = CEM_Exec.Range("User_Start")    
    End = CEM_Exec.Range("User_End")    
    For i = Start To End    
        Call Sub"i"    
    Next i    
End Sub
```

Comment: Name things. Methods ("subroutines") should have a name that starts with a verb, and just by reading the name, you should be able to tell what they do. `Sub1`, `Sub2` and `Sub23` don't mean anything, other than "gosh I don't want to be maintaining that code".

Comment: If your code is in a class module, look into `CallByName`. Otherwise if your code is in a standard code module, `Application.Run` will do.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming all the intended procedures are housed in Module1,

```
  Sub test()    
        Dim i As Integer    
        Dim intStart As Integer    
        Dim intEnd As Integer    
        intStart = CEM_Exec.Range("User_Start")    
        intEnd = CEM_Exec.Range("User_End")    
        For i = intStart To intEnd    
            Application.run "Module1.Sub" & i
        Next i    
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I think simple solution to your problem is using `Select Case` in `For` loop.

```
Sub test()
    Dim i As Integer, Start_Num As Integer, End_Num As Integer
    Start_Num = CEM_Exec.Range("User_Start")
    End_Num = CEM_Exec.Range("User_End")
    For i = Start_Num To End_Num
        Select Case i
            Case 1
                Call Sub1
            Case 2
                Call Sub2
            Case 3
                Call Sub3
                'and so on
                '
                '
                '
                '
            Case Else
                'Error message
        End Select
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Application.Run` method, along with the name of the procedure:

Note: `End` is a reserved word in VBA, so you'll be safer using a variable named iEnd (I've updated `Start` and `End` to be `iStart` and `iEnd`.

```
Sub test()    
    Dim i As Integer    
    Dim iStart As Integer    
    Dim iEnd As Integer    
    iStart = CEM_Exec.Range("User_Start")    
    iEnd = CEM_Exec.Range("User_End")    
    For i = iStart To iEnd    
        Application.Run "Sub" & i    
    Next i    
End Sub
```